# Can we stop upvoting posts as "Thank you for asking" and "Thank you for answering"?

Tags: discussion, voting

The tooltip for upvote shows:

> Question: This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.
>
> Answer: This answer is useful.

The tooltip for downvote shows:

> Question: This question does not show any research effort; it is
>   unclear or not useful.
>
> Answer: This answer is not useful.

I will not list all the questions and answers that have been blindly upvoted because there are too many posts to list in one page. Can we please stop voting just because a post is made by users?

One user once said he doesn't feel it necessary to edit his question because he's received three upvotes. Upvoting a poorly written post misleads users into believing that what they posted is clear and useful. No, there are many cases where:

1. Questions and answers are not useful and don't even make any sense.
2. Answers are blatantly wrong.
3. Questions and answers don't show any context/example/reference.
4. Questions and answers don't show any research efforts.

Please stop voting to express "Thank you for asking a question" and "Thank you for answering a question". That's doing a disservice to this community.

What is your thought?

Comment: Just passing by. Wanted to mention that almost all the answers I received was pretty helpful. I had this same thought but then I upvoted anyway since I wasn't upvoting for the sake of answering. I have seen upvotes of bad answers too but IMHO most of the time our answers really are quite helpful (subjectively that is). What I mean is perhaps the bad upvotes are the inevitable errors rather than a bad site culture?

Answer (score 2):

As likely as not, this is a side effect of the *vote early, vote often* ethos of young beta sites.  A lot of good posts get voted up in the early days, but a few poorer posts get swept up in the enthusiasm.

I've seen similar effects on other sites during their first couple of months.  It should settle down.  Especially now that you've drawn attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Please stop voting to express "Thank you for asking a question" and "Thank you for answering a question". That's doing a disservice to this community.

I agree totally that it shouldn't be a 'thank you' that's given *regardless* of quality.

> 1.Questions are not useful and don't even make any sense.
>
> 2.Answers are blatantly wrong.

I think most people would agree there.

We don't have that many strong Korean speakers on the site yet, and some people may read and upvote an answer if it seems plausible, rather than knowing that it's right. I think it's fair to suggest that people should think twice...

...but - ultimately, upvoting is what drives the site - it's what gives users the rep levels [measured in our stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language), and it's what gives other users the powers to clean and moderate the site. It also encourages people to participate. So we don't want to be too reluctant to upvote either.

As with many things in life, there's a balance to be struck.

> 3.Questions and answers don't show any context/example/reference.
>
> 4.Questions and answers don't show any research efforts.

We don't have any blanket rule on this site requiring context/example/reference - we only ask that they are given where necessary. In some cases, they won't be necessary to make the question clear.

As for showing research : we currently say, for general reference questions, that requests for help and clarification after consulting a resource may be acceptable. In this particular case, I would say that the research done should be mentioned.

In other cases, references may or may not be useful, and I think it's up to users to make their own judgements.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Over in Jp.SE, I give lots of UpVotes to newcomers, as a show / sign of "welcome!" . . .   (and Thank you! for not editing my posts.)</sub>

I imagine that for someone with less than 20 rep. points, it could be (and is probably is) a great thrill to get an  UpVote  and +5 or +10 points.  I often can't resist the temptation to be a bringer of that thrill.  -- provided, of course, that the post is good.

I feel pretty much the same way for a poster with less than 100 rep. points.

---

> [ One user once said he doesn't feel it necessary to edit his question because he's received three upvotes. ]

Interesting.  I just saw a user saying  " Two users upvoted my comment. " --- meaning that he doesn't feel it necessary to reconsider  his comment or its tone because he's received two upvotes.